# joomla module to display in every pages

Tags: joomla, module, publish, virtuemart

I am new to Joomla and Virtuemart. I am using Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart 1.1.9 and developing a website for online book sales. For my site I have created my own template. On my site's frontpage I have displayed a "category" module and everything is working fine.

But my problem is I want to show this "category" module on every page of my website and I don't know how to do it. In the back end I tried the following steps:

`Module Manger->Categories->Menu Assignment->Menu Items`, but in the list of menu items I can't see the pages that are related to my template.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: the menu items in the Menu Assignment are not associated with the template. This section simply displays the menu items you have created. Try creating a new menu item for the "main menu" and seeing it it appears there.

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using the no longer supported versions of Joomla! and Virtuemart?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to see a list of pages related to your template, all you would need to do is select the `All` option under `Menu Assignment` for the module. This will make the module show on every page.

Comment: I just created a module and and assigned it to all pages. But I am not able to see moudle in every page.. I just added a test message in my module. it is not appearing in any page